# Difference between an empty array and an array set to nil when fetching objects?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsarray, fetch, null

From the lynda.com core data course. Simon mentioned that if the `fetchedobjects` array WAS empty, i.e. there are no managed objects in the store then the code would work fine and no error would be logged.

However if the `fetchedobjects` array was set to `nil` then the error would display.

But isnt the `fetchedobjects` array set to `nil` when the pointer of the array is created (a line before the if statement)?

I might be having trouble differentiating between a `nil` array and an empty array. Can someone untangle this for me? thankyou.

```
- (IBAction)fetchObjects:(id)sender {

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Course" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Problem! %@",error);
}

for (Course *c in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"Course: %@ by author: %@", c.title, c.author);
}

}
```

Comment: If you just want to check for "no results", you can use `array.count == 0`. This will be `YES` for both `nil` and an empty array. Otherwise the difference is as specified by @Abizem's answer.

Comment: This is a bad idea, because it doesn't differentiate between the case of a failed method call, and a successful call that returns no results.  They are two different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The isn't such a thing as a nil array, the proper description is that it is an NSArray pointer that points to `nil` an empty array is an NSArray pointer that points to a valid NSArray object that has no members.

In the code you are talking about, fetched objects isn't set to nil, it is set to the result of the method call.  If the method call fails, then it returns nil, and populates the NSError parameter, if it succeeds it returns an array, which could be empty if no results are found.

Answer (score 2):

This answer does not respond to the fetchedobjects message but rather points out the differences between an empty array and a nil array (or any nil object for that matter)

Objective C will respond with nil to any message sent to a nil object. This is by design to allow code that checks against things like count == 0 just like you are doing.

Any nil object will accept any message and respond with nil. But an array that has no objects will respond correctly to other things it is sent.

If the array is nil it will not perform any actual functions and will always respond nil to anything called on it.

The best practice is to check if the object is nil beforehand to determine other paths to handle when the object is not set.

nil is an object set to nothing. nil and 0 are similar but no the same. Mathematically nil and 0 are equivalent. therefore a nil array does not return 0 from array.count, rather it returns nil. however since nil and 0 are equivalent mathematically the result returns true.

I hope that clears this up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If `executeFetchRequest` returns `nil` then you should check the value of `error`.  Otherwise there is no error and `fetchedObjects` will contain an initialized `NSArray` that contains zero or more objects.

The line `NSError *error = nil;` is setting `error` to nil, although it's really unnecessary.

Comment: The `nil` is still recommended, especially if the code is not using ARC.